# Are these quantified formulas equivalent?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Is this formula  bellow

$$\lnot(\forall a,b,c \in X: (aRb \wedge aRc) \Rightarrow \exists d (bRd \wedge cRd))$$

equivalent to

$$\exists a,b,c \in X: (aRb \wedge aRc) \Rightarrow \not\exists d (bRd \wedge cRd)$$

and does the second part of the formula mean that an exclusive or(or nothing at all) is possible here namely that we have  $cRd$ or if we don't have $cRd$ we can have $bRd$ or if don't have that b and c relate to no other is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not equivalent.

The negation of: $$\forall a,b,c\in X\;[p\to q]$$ is: $$\exists a,b,c\in X\;[p\wedge\neg q]$$

Note that $p\wedge\neg q$ and $p\to\neg q$ are not equivalent.

Comment: So the second part of the formula should be $\exists a,b,c \in X: (aRb \wedge aRc) \wedge (\not\exists d (bRd \wedge cRd))$ right? So that it is equivalent to $\lnot(\forall a,b,c \in X: (aRb \wedge aRc) \Rightarrow \exists d (bRd \wedge cRd))$

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Personally I don't use the sign you use, but $\neg\exists\cdots$.